# What are the loss functions used in teacher-student learning models?

Tags: objective-functions

I am not sure what are the common loss functions people usually use when training a student in a teacher-student learning model. Any insight on this is appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by teacher-student. Please link papers in which you were introduced to this term.